# Как сохранить список ArrayList в массив

Tags: java

Нужно сделать параметризованный класс, хранящий массив, с некоторой функциональностью `ArrayList` в виде функций `add(T el)`, `remove(int index)`, `get(int index)`.

Я пытаюсь в методах использовать ArrayList, но у меня возникает проблема, как потом сохранить полученный список в правильно параметризованный массив того типа, элемент которого мы получаем.

Код функции приведен частично.

```
static class DynamicArray<T> {
    private T[] array;

    public NewDynamicArray() { 
    }        

    public void add(T el) {                
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();   
        list.add(el); 
        array = (T[]) list.toArray( // здесь ошибка приведения
            new DynamicArray[list.size()]
        );
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Если кратко - в Java такое невозможно: `T[] array = new T[list.size()]`. Из-за стирания типов (type erasure) не получится создать массив обобщённого типа, будет создаваться `Object[]`.

Внутри класса не хранится никакой информации о его типе-параметре. Эта информация доступна только на этапе компиляции и стирается (становится недоступной) в runtime. Это происходит по историческим причинам, чтобы не ломать совместимость со старым кодом.

Впрочем, давай пока не будем забегать очень далеко, может быть, решение на поверхности.

Например, есть библиотеки, в которых уже реализованы коллекции примитивных типов. Так же советую сформулировать задачу. Возможно, есть другие решения.

На страничке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522284/convert-a-generic-list-to-an-array этот вопрос уже был рассмотрен. Представлен даже хак с рефлексией, как обойти данное ограничение, но не советую его использовать, особенно в производстве.

Answer (score 0):

Вы почему-то передаете как аргумент свой класс. Как метод может его преобразовать в массив?

Воспользуйтесь `toArray()` без аргументов:

```
array = (T[]) list.toArray();
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!